# Приравнять переменную php к тому, что выведет браузер (иммитация копипастинья)

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа (вопрос в стиле мсье).

Есть переменная - содержимое каракозябры. Каракозябры **при выводе в браузере - нет проблем**. Но при записывании в БД, и потом считывании - каракозябры. Если скопировать с монитора, или из исходного кода выдернуть - скопированное, в нужном мне виде, т.е. нет проблем. Сейчас, достаю из БД/таблицы данные - в ручную переношу в эту же БД/таблицу данные. Ручками - не очень производительно 8-)

Вопрос: можно ли переменную на PHP, каким либо образом вывести, и скопировать то, что вывел браузер, далее приравнять переменную к новому значению. т.е. с имитировать вывод/копирование/запись

p.s. Как сделать с нуля без Какакозябр - не вопрос, умею. Вопрос не в этом.

p.p.s. PHP,JS,JQ - способ не интересует. Производительность - неважно, главное не руками.

p.p.p.s. пробовал исходный код страницы записывать в текстовый файл - Каракозыбры. Если скопипастить - нет проблем. Так что думаю дело не в кодировках при записи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вы занимаетесь ерундой.

Попробуйте вот это: «[Как распознать кракозябры?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/)»

Но если религия запрещает перекодировать просто и хотите сложно и именно браузер — пробуйте средства для автоматизации/CI типа [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) или [Capybara](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit). [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), по идее, должно хватить.

Comment: Неистово плюсую. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Ссылка хороша. Можно брать на вооружение. Только я спросил кое что другое

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду парсинг? http://hashcode.ru/questions/132350/парсинг-html-страницы

Comment: Парсинг вещь хорошая. Пробовал уже. Каракозябры копируются 1 в 1. Так же пробовал определять кодировку переменной, и заменять спец командой. Еще грузить iframe и вылавливать GET'ом. Да еще много чего. В итоге есть данные, которые могу вывести без глюков, и если скопипастить то все работает, остальные способы нет. Вот и спрашиваю. Интересует, любой метод **эмитирующий** копипастинье.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте кодировки таблиц базы (в "операциях") и кодировки полей таблиц (в "структуре"). Также можете попробовать добавить эти строки в файл, где происходит соединения с базой.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET collation_connection='utf8_general_ci");
mysql_query("SET collation_server='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_server='utf8'");
```

Comment: Обижаете, я уже написал, что кодировку менять пробовал, до создания темы. Вопрос не как вывести данные из бд, а как считать, исправить, и записать. Пока работает только ручками.

Answer (score 0):

Прально человек топнул в сторону кодировки. Почитайте, пожалуйста, про [my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf).

Comment: Каракозябры успешно разобраны, спасибо. Вопрос не про распознавание к сожалению. 8-(