# Использование буфера обмена на странице, автоматическое копирование и вставка

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Страница загружает форму с input'ами. В input'ах значения уже заранее заполнены. Ну допустим:

```
<input name="d11" value="<? echo $d11; ?>">
<input name="d12" value="<? echo $d12; ?>">
....
<input name="d19" value="<? echo $d19; ?>">
```

Так же на странице есть и другие input'ы (принадлежат к другой форме)

```
<input name="r11" value="">
<input name="r12" value="">
....
<input name="r19" value="">
```

Вопрос: можно ли после загрузки страницы, автоматически скопировать все значения из input'ов в первой форме, т.е. с эмитировать нажатие Ctrl+C, и вставить скопированные значения в input'ы во второй форме?

Поясню.

1. Конечно, можно это сделать и в коде страницы. Так умею. Спрашиваю по другой причине.
2. Можно написать легкий js код, который приравняет значения, где нужно к тому, что нужно. Мне нужно именно имитировать это действие так, как если бы человек это сам скопировал и вставил
3. Скопировать код - не то. получится новое ТОЧНО равно скопированному. когда делаешь Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V - это не всегда точно. это мне и нужно

p.s. Собственно очень надеюсь получить ответ, и готов щедро наградить очками опыта ответившего.

p.p.s. Просьба [войти в положение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/131038/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-php-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F) в силу влияния черных сил.

добавлю после пары часов советов, для IE (только копирование):

```
<script>
    window.clipboardData.setData('text', 'Этот текст в буфере');
</script>
// осталось дописать вставку
```

Comment: А не проще ли "клонировать" первую форму? [.clone()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: "когда делаешь Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V - это не всегда точно..."     

это как о_О ?

Comment: могу в гости пригласить. показать наглядно. но просьба поверить на слово. если начать с простого. я загружаю страницу, нужно с эмитировать такое действие что у меня в буфере будет фраза - привет всем пацаны!!1. так что бы я ее не видел, и если закрыл браузер, и открыл любое приложение и нажал Ctrl+V. я вставил фразу, которая автоматически с копировалась в буфер при загрузке страницы? это будет 1/2 того, что мне нужно.

Comment: простите за оффтоп но последний коммент это ппц))

Comment: у вас есть Форма1 и Форма2. Загружается страница... value инпутов Формы1 копируются в value инпутов Формы2 ?

Comment: загружается страница, в форме 1 есть данные (сразу). форма 2 - пуста. вот смысл скопировать из одной во вторую. (в данный момент ручками).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/bQTTm/

так ? :)

Comment: пример хороший, но не то, что хотел. скопировал, попробовал после использования этого кода открыть на компьютере простой блокнот и нажать Ctrl+V -> все пусто. значит копирование было не через буфер обмена. почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вам надо скопировать в буфер? Это судя по вашему последнему комментарию.[То что предлагает FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Clipboard), а для IE:

```
function copyToClipboard(s) {
    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
        clipboardData.setData('text', s);
    }
}
```

Так же cмотрите этот плагин [Clipboard plugin for jQuery](http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/). Кроме того, почитайте [эту статейку](http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/). Инфы - не паханное поле!

Comment: вот для IE

    <script>
        window.clipboardData.setData('text', 'Этот текст в буфере');
    </script>

собственно, уже вперед. теперь как его после копирования в буфер его из буфера вставить куда нужно?

Comment: поскольку вставку не нашел, думаю что решения нету